# What should I write in .htaccess file to rewrite this url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a server parked on xyz.com. I have Wordpress installed on xyz.com/ and xyz.com/blog. I have created a new directory xyz.com/mamba.

In **xyz.com/mamba**. I want what that if user visits xyz.com/mamba/hello then the url should be rewritten to **xyz.com/mamba/index.php?message=hello**.

What should I write in .htaccess file in xyz.com/mamba/ directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mamba/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?message=$1 [L]
```

The first line turns on the rewrite engine for the `/mamba/` directory. Without doing this, the rules won't get applied (and the rules in the parent directory gets applied instead). The `RewriteBase` tells the rules here that any relative URI in the target should have `/mamba/` as a base URI. The 2 conditions say that the request must not point to an existing file or directory, and the rule rewrites the request and puts it in the `message` query string parameter for `index.php`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please refer me some link where this all is easily explained? I am getting hard time in grasping the concept of how .htaccess works.

Comment: @UmairKhanJadoon Probably the [apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation, they also have a [rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/).